# Leksah hangs on first startup

Tags: haskell, leksah

When I start leksah an input form is shown (see image below). The problem is no matter what I do, nothing happens when I click on `OK` or on `Cancel`.
I was never able to get past this screen. I click multiple times on the two buttons in the lower right corner. Nothing.

Any idea how I can collect the meta data or skip this step?

[image: leksah error]

Comment: This kinda question would be better suited for the Leksah forums (or maybe submit an issue if it's indeed a bug).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted in the leksah forum and someone posted a workaround.

The Answer is in this forum post:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/leksah/haFR25h7Bkw

> Ok, finally I've got it working. As I understand, welcome screen
>   appears if there isn't any preferences file in ~/.leksah-0.13/
>   directory. So I just copied prefs.lkshp file from
>   ~/.cabal/share/x86_64-linux-ghc-7.6.3/leksah-0.13.3.0/data and
>   restarted leksah. This time it opened with default 'leksah-welcome'
>   session. I hope this tips will help you. Sorry about my awful english.
>   Cheers, Alex

Then:

> I encountered the same problem. If you only copy "prefs.lkshp" file
>   you will get the "Error reading file....Unexpected 'M'" message. 
>   However it will work if you copy both prefs.lkshp, AND prefscoll.lkshp